# sending email to users contact list?

Tags: asp.net

i have an application to retrieve an users contact list in a gridview...how do i send email to all the users from the users contact list??

Steps:-

1.User enters hi/her email id and password.
2.Clicks on send invites.
3.The button click event should send invitation email to all the contacts in users contact list.[ how to do the 3rd step??]

Comment: If the question is now to send an email, look at system.net.mail namespace. Use MailMessage and SMTPClient object to send email from .NET.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Are you having trouble with the contact list or just sending the email?

Comment: how will i retrieve the emails from the gridview and send email to 20 user at a time??should i save the emails to a database and then retrieve them or can i retrieve them directly from gridview and send them invites.here i am retrieving the contact list of gmai/yahoo users.

Comment: http://www.bindaasbargain.com/referral/customer/form/ i want the same thing for my site..to retrive contacts from gmail and send them invites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the code to send off a batch (List) of e-mails. Looping through a gridview row collection is fairly straightforward and you should check out that link I provided. Here is a small code snippet to get you started.

```
        List<string> emails = new List<string>();
        foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                emails.Add(row.Cells[0].Text); // provided that index 0 is the e-mail address
            }
        }

        // fire off the e-mails
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SendEmail(List<string> emailAddresses)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            mail.From = new MailAddress("Some From Address");

            foreach (string email in emailAddresses)
            {
                mail.To.Add(email);
            }

            mail.Subject = "Some Message Title";
            mail.Body = "Some Message Body";

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("Some Relay Server");

        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientException exc)
        {
            // Log Exception.
        }
    }
```

Comment: how will i retrieve the emails from the gridview and send email to 20 user at a time??should i save the emails to a database and then retrieve them or can i retrieve them directly from gridview and send them invites.

Comment: I would loop the rows in the GridView and add all the e-mail addresses into a List. Once that is done, you can send them all at once in a separate thread. There are plenty of examples of how to loop through a GridView, but here is one to get you started: http://shawpnendu.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-loop-through-gridview-rows.html

Comment: thanks :) can u guide me with how to send emails in batch of 20??

Comment: Did my responses answer you're question? I posted the code to loop through the grid as well as the code to fire off a "batch" which is a List of e-mail address.